# Discussing this system of equations in terms of a parameter, $m$

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

I need to tell if the following system of equations has either:

- A unique solution, or
- Infinite solutions, or
- No solutions at all.

(for all possible $R$eal values of the given parameter, $m$)

To solve this question I decided to use the well-known [Rouché-Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem). The system of equations under study is: $$\begin{cases} x + my + z = 0 \\ mx – y + 3z = 0\\ x - 3y + mz =0\end{cases}$$

Let's study the rank of the augmented matrix, which I will call $A^*$:
$$A^*=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & m & 1 & 0\\ m & -1 & 3 & 0\\ 1 & -3 & m & 0\end{array}\right)\sim \ldots \sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & m & 1 & 0\\ 0 & (1+m^2)(3+m) & m^2-9 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 10-m-m^3 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

I obtained the last equivalent matrix after several operations I performed on the original augmented matrix. I double-checked that it is correct, which I'm 100% confident it is.

The thing is that, for $m=2$, both the augmented matrix ($A^*$) and the coefficient matrix ($A$) have rank equal to 2, so there would be infinite solutions in this case.

### **Now my question**

If you give the previous matrix a second look, you will notice that, for $m=-3$, the rank of both $A^*$ and $A$ would be 2 again:
$$A^*(m=-3)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & -3 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 40 & 0\end{array}\right)\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & -3 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 40 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

And the solutions would be given by: $$\left(\begin{array} \\x \\ y \\ z\end{array}\right)=\lambda\,\left(\begin{array} \\3\\ 1\\ 0\end{array}\right)$$

However this is incorrect. Following my book's solution, **$m=-3$ is no special case**. But why? We can clearly see that the rank of the system would still be 2, and in theory there would be infinite solutions (rather than just the trivial solution, $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$)

Where did I go wrong? Why do I get $m=-3$ as a special case?

### **EDIT**

Let me add the operations I performed on $A^*$ to put it in its [Row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form):
[image: system-of-equations]

Comment: What are exactly the operations you performed ? just taking the determinant of $A$ ($10-m-m^3$) leads to exactly the same result as your textbook so the problem is most certainly here.

Comment: @Moo It was a typo, nothing changes. Thanks for pointing it out, I corrected it!

Comment: Hi @Delta-u, let me add an image with the operations I performed, it's pretty straightforward. However I don't know why it didn't work. I know that the determinant of $A$ gives $m=2$ as the only solution, but I just want to know why my solution didn't work as it should.

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia: For that matrix, the CP is $$-m^3-m+10$$ The roots of this are $$m = 2, -1~ \pm ~2i$$ What am I missing since $3$ is not a root of the determinant?

Comment: @Moo I followed another procedure. Instead of calculating the determinant of $A^*$, I reduced $A^*$ to its row-echelon form so I can study its rank. From there I will be able to use the Rouche-Capelli theorem (Please check the end of the updated answer). Following this procedure, which should be correct, should yield all special values of $m$ that I would need to have into account

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia. Hi Jose. In the third step, you multiply second row by $(m+3)$, which is fine, UNLESS $m=-3$, in which case you are multiplying a row by zero, which is not allowed. So, you are introducing the $m=-3$ case in the procedure to the row echelon form.

Comment: That was the issue... thanks @Zamu ! By the way guys do you think reducing a matrix to its row echelon form (when I have 1 or 2 parameters) is the best/fastest way to go in order to discuss a system of equations? Or do you prefer to compute the determinant directly? I need to save as much time as possible during the exam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your computation of the rank of $A^*$ to go from the third matrix to the fourth you multiply the second row by $(3+m)$. But this is a rank preserving operation only if $3+m \neq 0$.

Comment: Wow!! That was a big mistake. So if I multiply a row by (m+3) I would need to specify that m can't be equal to 3 right? I think I actually didn't need to multiply the entire row by (m+3), I should have just done it in my head in order to reduce the last row.

Comment: Yes exactly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: eliminating the variables $y,z$ i got $$x(m^3+m-10)=0$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Yes @DrSonnhardGraubner I do understand it now. Thank you for your time :)